# Regular Expression Pattern for C# with matches

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on project where I need to find Frequency from a given text. I wrote a Regular expression that try to detect frequency, however I am stuck with how C# handle it and how exactly I use it in my software

My regular experssion is `(\d*)(([,\.]?\s*((k|m)?hz)*)|(\s*((k|m)?hz)*))$`

And I am trying to find value from

- 23,2 Hz
- 24,4Hz
- 25,0 Hzsadf
- 26 Hz
- 27Khz
- 28hzzhzhzhdhdwe
- 29
- 30.4Hz
- 31.8 Hz
- 4343.34.234 Khz
- 65SD

Further Explanation:

1. System needs to work for US and Belgium Culture hence, 23.2 (US) = 23,2 (Be)
2. I try to find a Digit, followed by either khz,mhz,hz or space or , or .
3. If it is , or . then it should have another Digit followed by khz, mhz, hz

Any help is appericated.

Comment: You didn't specify what the results should be (so, with only inputs, it is difficult to know the outputs required). Perhaps hand rolling a parser of your own may be a better option.

Comment: This is Error case :). I am trying to find frequency only.

Comment: @Oded, I am trying to find frequency [first line of my message says it too ], so I generate those case where I can or cannot have valid frequency. I will get short text like one of item listed above, not complete sentence. If that helps

Comment: Examples speak louder than words that can be misinterpreted. What if someone reading believes 65SD is a valid frequency notation in their language/region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running replace

```
(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*([KkMm]?[Hh][Zz])
```

for `($1 $2)` gives

```
(23,2 Hz)
(24,4 Hz)
(25,0 Hz)sadf
(26 Hz)
(27 Khz)
(28 hz)zhzhzhdhdwe
29
(30.4 Hz)
(31.8 Hz)
4343.(34.234 Khz)
65SD
```

Any corrections to desired behavior?

**upd**: this is with negative lookbehind and word boundary:

```
(?<![.,0-9])(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*([KkMm]?[Hh][Zz])\b

(23,2 Hz)
(24,4 Hz)
25,0 Hzsadf
(26 Hz)
(27 Khz)
28hzzhzhzhdhdwe
29
(30.4 Hz)
(31.8 Hz)
4343.34.234 Khz
65SD
```

Comment: Thanks I Am still trying to understand what you wrote, but I need 29 to be matched as well :)... If not, I can use filter it manually though

Comment: I am going to explain the expression after we get it working as required. That 29 is a match kind of screws the things though - it will have to match any number this way or is <spaces>29<spaces> all your input in this case?

Comment: Do you mind telling me what does : (?:[.,]\d+)? means, specifically why we have ? at end when we close it with paranthesis

Comment: I am so excited for your effort and really amaze at your speed to write it, I am trying this for 3 hrs now...

Comment: `(?:[.,]\d+)?` is a non-capturing group (the `(?:` to `)` thing), which may appear 0 or 1 times (last `?`), inside which we expect either dot or comma `[.,]` and one or more digit `\d+`. This is to match fractional part.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. it is so simple after I understand it. Damn Regular expression always confuse me. Thanks a lot for your quick help @Eugene.